# Django/Django nonrel + Google App Engine + Tutorial

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm starting to learn how to use Django on the Google App Engine.

I had search about some introducing tutorials, like [this one](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel).

But looks like isn't really updated (November, 2010).

I really appreciate if someone could point to me a good tutorial, updated (to works with the latest stable release of django/django-nonrel and GAE).

(Strange, why the tutorials tag is not allowed?)

Comment: This [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NHX8HsCuJ4) works for me. But maybe we have something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it up and runnining, with very little Django or App Engine experience, using this:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

The one big difference I would say is grab the source from the django-nonrel github account, which is more recent than the ones indicated in that tutorial

https://github.com/django-nonrel

Note, allbuttonspressed is outdated, use the following:

http://django-nonrel.org/
http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/

Comment: Is there a tutorial in the first link? I've take a look on it before, but looks like just how to unzip the things and describing some characteristics of each package.

Comment: What kind of tutorial do you need?  Have you used App Engine at all?  Pretty much all you need to do is unzip all the files into a folder and use that as your App Engine folder.  It even provides app.yaml for you.  You might want to edit that to change the app name, but otherwise everything is there ready to go.

Comment: I was searching about a intro tutorial, developing some easy application. But, in fact I can go ahead from here. The link that I had posted above and yours helped me. Thx.

Comment: Glad you're up and running.  I know the django-nonrel team is looking for help on documentation.  If you have notes on what setup information is missing I'm sure they'd appreciate contributions.

Comment: interesting. Maybe I will send a e-mail for them. Cya.

Comment: Note, allbuttonspressed is now very old and unmaintained. I too was able to get it running, but it involved a massive amount of work.